# How to catch an ENOENT with nodejs child_process exec

Tags: node.js, typescript, exec, child-process

I'm trying to run the following code without the internet connection.

```
myExt = ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --install-extension msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome"

      console.log(myExt);
      const { error, stdout, stderr } = await exec(myExt);
      if (error) {
        console.error(`error: ${error}`);
      } else {
        console.log(stdout);
        addedExtensions.push(missExt);
      }
```

**The problem is i dont get the error inside stderr**

When i run from command i get the following error

```
C:\Users\shana>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin\code" --install-extension msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome
getaddrinfo ENOENT marketplace.visualstudio.com:443
```

How i can handle exception that is coming from command prompt

Comment: This is the whole output? Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: Yes this is the complete output of command prompt upon failure,  on successful it shows only one of completion

Comment: what about `stderr` variable is it contain something useful?

Comment: Im getting undefined in error and SAME object in stderr and stdout

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> const { error, stdout, stderr } = await exec(myExt);

These process is not await able so we cant just simple put await and async on it.
Instead i had to convert into the promise and then use in standard await/async

Something Like  "

```
    let result =  await new Promise<boolean>(res=>{
    exec(myExt,function(err,stdOut,stdErr)
    {
    // TO Work
    res(true);
    }
    },rej=>{});
    console.log(result); //True
```